# onclick event triggers twice in IE but not in FF or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have an onclick event on a div that wraps a label and a span. In IE, if the label is clicked, the event is triggered twice, if the span is clicked the event is triggered once. This doesn't happen in other browsers. Here is an example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function showHide(id) {
        var node = document.getElementById(id);
        if (node.style.display != "none")
            node.style.display = 'none';
        else
            node.style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div onclick="showHide('expandDiv')">
        <label id="outLabel" for="outText">Label</label>
        <span id="outText">This is an example of an</span>
    </div>
    <div id="expandDiv" style="display:block">
        <p>Expanded Div</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to put your condition in a curly braces

Comment: That didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Why do you have a label for a span?

Comment: This is just an example that I sliced out of my project. I just stripped out everything else that I felt was unnecessary to answering the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly shorter version.

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="showHide('expandDiv', event)">
```

**JS**

```
function showHide(id, event) {
  var node         = document.getElementById(id),
      curr_display = node.style.display;

  node.style.display = curr_display === "block" ? "none" : "block";   
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/1w4dxdkm/

Comment: I also discovered you can do it without passing an event in as an argument. What will happen in IE is that when it reaches event.preventDefault(); it will affect the global window.event variable, preventing it from firing off again. This won't affect other browsers because they require event to be passed in as an argument if you want to be able to modify an event. Still doesn't quite explain why label was affected but not span...

Answer (score 1):

adding `event.preventDefault();` works as expected in IE and Chrome

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function showHide(id) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var node = document.getElementById(id);
        if (node.style.display != "none"){
            node.style.display = 'none';
        }else{
            node.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div onclick="showHide('expandDiv')">
        <label id="outLabel" for="outText">Label</label>
        <span id="outText">This is an example of an</span>
    </div>
    <div id="expandDiv" style="display:block">
        <p>Expanded Div</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you have to define `event` first?

Comment: It won't work in Firefox unless you define `event` properly.

Comment: Placing event.preventDefault(); at the beginning of the function doesn't work but placing it at the end did.

Comment: @John - It should work anywhere in the function (except in a conditional block that isn't executed, obviously). If it didn't work at the beginning there must be some other problem in the function. (But as per previous comments `event` does need to be defined if you want it to work in all browsers.)

Comment: @nnnnnn True, it did work when I passed event in as an argument.